# Observe all functions being called in an application

Tags: java, rmi, xml-rpc, observer-pattern

I am starting out to build a remote collaboration application.

What I want is for all the actions made in one application to be exactly replicated in an application running in a remote computer.

Kind of like remote desktop/teamviewer - but I need to **call the same function** in the remote computer rather than transmit image difference information.

I need to modify an existing application and add in the collaboration part.

I have looked into XML-RPC and RMI as ways to execute the commands remotely.

**What I want is a method to capture all function calls made in the application.**

Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Aspect Oriented Programming Framework (AOP) like JBoss AOP, AspectJ etc.

http://www.jboss.org/jbossaop

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj

So you do not have to modify anything of the existing sourcecode.